# Web3.py cannot connect to geth --dev node via IPC

Tags: go-ethereum, web3.py, geth-debugging, mac-osx, ipc

I've launched a geth client over IPC:

```
geth --dev --allow-insecure-unlock --ipcpath ipc://$HOME/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc
```

And trying to connect using a Web3 IPC provider:

```py
my_provider = Web3.IPCProvider('ipc://$HOME/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc')
```

which doesn't work with the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Also I don't see a `geth.ipc` file in my `Ethereum` folder after the `geth` client is launched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need to specify the path as follows:

```
$ geth --dev --allow-insecure-unlock --ipcpath $HOME/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc
```

Then you can find your `geth.ipc` file:

```
$ ls Library/Ethereum/
geth.ipc
```

Web3.py

```
>>> from web3 import Web3
>>> my_provider = Web3.IPCProvider("$HOME/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc")
>>> my_provider
<web3.providers.ipc.IPCProvider object at 0x7f32f633bfd0>
```

From the [docs](https://geth.ethereum.org/interface/Command-Line-Options):

```
  --ipcpath     Filename for IPC socket/pipe within the datadir (explicit paths escape it)
```

Comment: Just a small note, `$HOME` didn't work for me in `web3`, but `~` did. There was a PR that uses `pathlib` to resolve home directories using `~`.